# strange characters in URL while displaying in PHP

Tags: php

I am using PHP to display a fileserver path.

What I am getting now:

```
file:%22////filsrv//logs//Test//D_log1.1.1%22
```

I am using this method to strip

```
$rs1 = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","",urldecode($row['ResultDirectory']));
```

but I am not sure If I am using the right one,

The actual Path stored in the DB is :

```
\\filsrv\logs\Test\D_log1.1.1
```

missing anything?
Thanks,

Comment: %22 is `"` - does that ring a bell?

Comment: Please add an answer outlining how you got it solved, and self-accept it to close the question. You can accept your own question after 24 hours or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, resolved with this

```
echo '<a href=file:'.$rs1.'</>';
```

to

```
echo '<a href='.$rs1.'</>';
```